# Openwayback search does not work with arabic website in URL

Tags: arabic, webarchive, warc

I have installed and setup the [basic of openwayback](https://github.com/iipc/openwayback/wiki/How-to-configure) and now try to make it work with the following resource

```
https://moj.gov.ae/documents/21128/102233/قرار+مجلس+الوزراء+رقم+18+لسنة+2017+بشأن+اعتماد+قائمة+الاشخاص+والتنظيمات+الارهابية.pdf
```

**Setup:**

1. I used [webrecorder.io](https://webrecorder.io/) to download the warc file of the above.
2. Config openwayback to bare minimum and put warc file into the data folder
3. Open web app try to search for that exact address

**Results:**

1. Nothing is found. The address turn into

   http://localhost:8855/wayback/19960101000000-20181231235959*/https://moj.gov.ae/documents/21128/102233/????+????+???????+???+18+????+2017+????+??????+?????+???????+??????????+?????????.pdf
2. But for example if I put only https://moj.gov.ae then I can found the document in the form of `URL encoded`.
   But even if I copy that whole URL encoding into the search bar, nothing comes up.

**What I expect:**

1. If you copy the whole URL,arabic or not, that particular document must show up
2. The result of the search should be non-encoded form

Is there any setting that I missed?

Comment: The path of that url has a mixture of left-to-right and right-to-left codepoints. I know enough about Unicode to know that's something that is complicated!